# PUNICODE_STRING doesn't work with winternl.h

Tags: dll

today I try to pass a string unicode string and go through NewRtlInitUnicodeString.

To use this function, I need to include winternl.h. But once it's done, it still does not work:

```
#include <winternl.h>
FORCEINLINE VOID NewRtlInitUnicodeString(PUNICODE_STRING DestinationString, PWSTR SourceString)
{
DestinationString->Buffer = SourceString;
DestinationString->MaximumLength = DestinationString->Length = wcslen(SourceString) * sizeof(WCHAR);
}
```

Error : identifier "PUNICODE_STRING" not defined

PS : I use it in a DLL

Thanks you in advence.

Comment: That seems unlikely, PUNICODE_STRING is declared in winternl.h.  You'd better have a look at it to make sure it didn't get corrupted.

Comment: @HansPassant Yep, it was corrupted, thanks mate.